# Structure for a list

Tags: html, html-lists, accessibility, semantic-markup

Im trying to structure below menu, those items are related to the same context with a border in between what is the right way to construct the menu?

```
<ul>
     <li> ... </li>
     <li> ... </li>
</ul>
<ul>
     <li> ... </li>
     <li> ... </li>
</ul>
```

OR

```
<ul>
     <li> ... </li>
     <li class='separator'> ... </li>
     <li> ... </li>
     <li> ... </li>
 </ul>
```

End result menu:

[image: End result menu]

Comment: What’s the point of the separator? Just decoration, or does it convey something (e.g., does it group the links somehow)?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

I would pick this.

```
<ul>
     <li> ... </li>
     <li class='separator'> ... </li>
     <li> ... </li>
     <li> ... </li>
  </ul>
```

The rational behind my choice is that if the menu items belong to the same category, it gets easier to style them. For instance, if you wanted to add a border to the whole ul, its easier than trying to add specific classes to 2 ul s and do border-left, border-right etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this as accessibility, I have wandered in. If the items are all related and you want a screen reader to announce them as part of the same set, the second option is better:

```
<ul>
     <li> ... </li>
     <li class='separator'> ... </li>
     <li> ... </li>
     <li> ... </li>
 </ul>
```

However, sccreen reader users will hear a count that is higher than the actual number of menu items (assuming it has no content). If the separator is *strictly* visual, then consider hiding it from assistive technology, perhaps using `aria-hidden` on the `<li>`.

This assumes that your `<li class='separator'> ... </li>` has no meaningful menu content. If it *does* have content, then your second option is even better as now you can style it to display a visible separator (like a border) that will not be spoken to screen reader users at all.

If you still want to announce the separator to screen reader users, you can lean on content in the separator list item that you hide visually, or you can add an `aria-label`, `aria-labelledby`, or `aria-describedby` attribute depending on your case (if you tell me, I can guide you on this).